# Notification when a record in an SQLITE database gets too low

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

I'd like to be notified when inventory in an sqlite database drops below a certain level.

The amount drops by a set number every day, and I update the database via a cron job in the evening. The cron job reads something like:

```bash
cat update.sql | sqlite3 database.db
```

I have an `.sql` file that can tell me it's time to re-order. It contains an `.output` line that gives a filename, and if it's not time to re-order, the file is zero-length. I can test for that file's size; if it's bigger than zero, I need to read it, and if not, I can ignore it. It'd be simple enough to move that code into my `update.sql` file, and I can script the whole "check for the output file, test its size, holler if it's bigger than zero" thing.

What I'd prefer is to avoid the script and the intermediary file and have sqlite append a note to my daily reminders. Files designated as `.output` are overwritten, so I can't just use my reminder file as `.output`.

Is there a solution within sqlite that I haven't been able to find?

Comment: Note for the astute shell users among us: I just spotted the UUoC and will take the necessary steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't as much of an sqlite answer as I was looking for, but it's what I need.

I use [Dianne Skoll's remind](https://dianne.skoll.ca/projects/remind/) program for daily reminders, and I remembered that it allows for one data file to include others. So:

1. In my reminders file, I added the line, `include <path_to_reminders_files>/reorder.rem`.
2. In the .sql file I run to update my database every day, I added to the bottom:

```sql
.headers off
.output <path_to_reminders_files>/reorder.rem
SELECT "REM Time to re-order", name || '%' FROM <table_name> WHERE remaining/per_day < 30;
```

When there's a thirty day supply (or less) of an item left, I get a list of everything I need to re-order, and the fact that sqlite overwrites the output file (rather than appends to it) works in my favor.

Comment: Some might wonder why I don't just schedule regular deliveries. It's because the cron job isn't the only thing that updates the database. On occasion, I might use more or less of a thing than usual. I go in to the console and update the amount manually when that happens.